# Consulta que muestre rutas en las que no se ha vendido un producto en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito mostrar en una consulta las rutas en las que no se ha vendido el producto 5 en el año 2010

```
select r.[Descripcion]Ruta
from [dbo].[Rutas] r inner join [dbo].[Clientes] c
ON
r.[CodigoRuta] = c.[CodigoRuta] inner join [dbo].[Ventas] v
ON
c.[CodigoClientes] = v.[CodigoCliente] inner join [dbo].[VentasDetalle] vd
ON
v.[CodigoVentas] = vd.[CodigoVentas]
where vd.[CodigoProducto] NOT IN(5) and year(v.[Fecha]) = 2010
group by r.[Descripcion]
```

Comment: seria nejor una consulta, en donde pongas, el año, ruta , producto y no ventas. y despues filtrarias donde las ventas sean 0. Si quieres crea tus tablas en http://sqlfiddle.com/ o algo similar, agrega datos y comparte la liga para que asi te ayudemos a crear la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, buscamos todas las rutas dónde sí, hemos vendido el producto en cuestión en el año 2010:

```
select c.CodigoRuta
       from Ventas v
       inner join VentasDetalle vd
           on v.CoigoVentas = vd.CodigoVentas
       inner join Clientes c
           on v.CodigoCliente = c.CodigoCliente
       where vd.CodigoProducto = 5
             and year(v.Fecha) = 2010
       group by c.CodigoRuta
```

Ahora, usando el código anterior como ubconsulta, simplemente deberíamos listar las rutas que no estuvieran en este conjunto de datos:

```
select CodigoRuta,
       Descripcion
       from Rutas
       where CodigoRuta not in (
            select c.CodigoRuta
                   from Ventas v
                   inner join VentasDetalle vd
                       on v.CoigoVentas = vd.CodigoVentas
                   inner join Clientes c
                       on v.CodigoCliente = c.CodigoCliente
                   where vd.CodigoProducto = 5
                         and year(v.Fecha) = 2010
                   group by c.CodigoRuta
        )
```